# python udp socket.timeout on local machine

Tags: python, sockets, udp, socket-timeout-exception

So I'm making a basic "ping" application  using UDP for an assignment, and everything is working except the implementation of socket.settimeout().
I can't seem to figure out why, but it has to do with the bound socket. It might just be a quirk in Python but I'd like to confirm it before I document it.
I'm not looking for a functional code answer (that'd be cheating), but rather why what I have is broken. (e.g: some undocumented reason that Python doesn't like client/server on same machine etc)

Python Socket Timeout Details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

In the code represented below, the communication with server running on same machine is successful, but only when the client does not bind to the socket. But if it does not bind to the socket, the timeout system fails (this being tested by turning off the server, in which all ten timeouts get printed immediately and at once).

Note: Code is not ideal, but this is a networking theory class and not a programming class. It just has to work in the end. I could hand it in right now and get an A, but I want to understand why the timeout function does not work.

**EDIT:** To clarify an issue, the use of Bind in the client was after seeing the server code had it before I realized UDP doesn't need it, but it happened to make the timeout function work properly, but breaks the normal operation.
Could the socket.settimeout() declaration only work for TCP maybe?

Client Code (which has the timeout):

```
import socket
import time
import select


data = "Re-verify our range to target... one ping only. \n"

addrDest = ("127.0.0.1",8675)
addrLocal = ("127.0.0.1",12345)

totalTime = 0
averageTime = 0
totalPings = 0
#timeout_seconds = 1.0

UDPSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addrLocal) 
# adding bind here even though it's UDP makes timeout work,
# but breaks normal functionality
UDPSock.settimeout(1)


while (totalPings < 10):
 totalPings = (totalPings + 1)
 start = time.clock()
 str_list = []
 str_list.append(str(totalPings))
 str_list.append(" ")
 str_list.append(str(start))
 str_list.append(" ")
 str_list.append(data)
 dataOut = ''.join(str_list)
 UDPSock.sendto(dataOut,addrDest)
 try:
      dataIn,addrIn = UDPSock.recvfrom(1024)
      print dataIn.strip(),"\n",addrIn
      elapsed = ((time.clock() - start) * 1000)
      print elapsed, " ms round trip"
 except socket.error:
      print "Connection timed out for Packet #", totalPings
```

Server Code:

```
import socket

UDPSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# (to all IP addresses on this system)
listen_addr = ("",8675)
UDPSock.bind(listen_addr)

# Report on all data packets received and
# where they came from in each case (as this is
# UDP, each may be from a different source and it's
# up to the server to sort this out!)
while True:
    data,addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(1024)
    print data.strip(),addr
    UDPSock.sendto(data,addr)
```

Comment: if you want to use timeout for read: use `import select` and `select.select([UDPSock], [], [], timeout)`

Comment: I tried the select method. Overcomplicated things, and didn't really work well having to deal with everything returned as a list etc. In the end it turned out to be an exception thrown that the connection was forcibly closed when the server was turned off, that my general socket exception handler caught

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to bind to local address of the client? Will the client act as a server too at any point? If not there is no need to bind the client at all. You need a specific port only if you need your client to act as a server, if you don't call bind it will create a random port no ranging from (0 - 1023 are reserved) 1024 - 65535 (if I remember correctly) and that will be Source Port in the UDP Packet, Source Address is the Address where client runs.

According to Berkley Sockets

```
bind() assigns a socket to an address. When a socket is created using socket(), 
it is only given a protocol family, but not assigned an address. This association with an address must be performed with the bind() system call before the socket can accept connections to other hosts
```

If this is a Networking class project and you are trying to implement Client-Server architecture then you should never call **bind** from within your client code because Client should never act as a Server and Client should connect to a listening Server not Server connecting to Client.

**Update:**

Bind may be required to be called from a TCP Client-Server design but not from a UDP Client-Server model because UDP is a send and forget design and doesn't have low level packet send success acknowledgement. A UDP packet will have Source Address and Port within itself.

Comment: Thanks. I tried bind while attempting to fix the timeout issue, which it seems to work but breaks the actual functionality. The reason for for trying it was a seeing the server had it before realizing UDP doesn't need it, but it happened to make the timeout after 1 second work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem by removing the exception handling. There is a socket error when the server is turned off, specifically "socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when it tries to read from the socket.
This apparently ignores the timeout function when the socket is not bound in Python (which is why the timeout worked when I bound it).
If I run the server, but just have it not send any data (by commenting the last line), the program times out correctly when it does not receive its packet back.
I am also going to use a more specific exception handler
In the end it's just a quirk in Python and the fact that UDP is connection-less.

Also, someone mentioned the use of "select" to solve this problem. I looked into it, and I would end up with an if...else statement block which kinda works, but the native exceptions are preferred.
Thanks all.

-Jimmy